# Write to file elapsed time, with chosen/known units

Tags: r, file-io, time, format

I am using R and Rstudio. I am a complete newbie.

I mean to write to file the time elapsed in each iteration of a loop. So I define three variables: `start <- Sys.time()` (at the beginning of code), and similarly `prevtime` and `currtime` (at the beginning and end of each iteration).

The values of variables are (e.g., last iteration)

```
> currtime - start
Time difference of 5.486106 mins
> currtime - prevtime
Time difference of 1.239183 secs
```

R automatically sets units. But then if I execute

```
> write( currtime - start, file = "test.Rout", append = F )
> write( currtime - prevtime, file = "test.Rout", append = T )
```

I get in `test.Rout`

```
5.486106
1.239183
```

with no units.

**Is there any way to force the units for writing to file (`write`), e.g., all to seconds, so there is no ambiguity?**

I guess I could scan the output of `currtime - prevtime` and find the units, but I am sure there is a very simple way to do this.

I guess I could also use `system.time(*{mycommands}*)`, but I think it would be easier to have variables assigned, since I might want to define time points in the middle of my loop, and get various time differences.

Comment: or you could just [microbenchmark](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html) the function. [See also](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html).

Comment: @hrbrmstr - microbenchmark seems to be suitable for what I need. And the link provided is interesting (although somewhat long). For my present needs, it appears that the answer of Pierre Lafortune is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try isolating the units and combining them to the time value:

```
start <- Sys.time()
currtime <- start + 180
diff.time <- currtime - start
timediff <- paste(diff.time, attr(diff.time, "units"))
write(timediff, file = "test.Rout", append = F )
```

---

**Explanation**

The object `diff.time` is of the class `difftime`. When you write it to file, the attributes are being dropped. Check `str(diff.time)` to see the structure:

```
str(diff.time)
Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:1] 3
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"
```

The attribute we are looking for is `"units"` and its value is `"mins"`. We can extract that attribute and `paste` it to the time difference.

***Checking attributes***

1. We can check the attributes with `attr("object", "name of attribute")`:

   ```
   attr(diff.time, "units")
   [1] "mins"
   ```
2. We can also check with `attributes` and subset list-style:

   ```
   attributes(diff.time)
   $units
   [1] "mins"

   $class
   [1] "difftime"
   ```

Comment: Can I coerce directly the units (without checking `attr` and converting if needed)?

Comment: I mean having `write( diff.time...` write only the number, always in seconds, instead of letting R decide which is the best.

Comment: Yes, you can do `difftime(currtime, start, units="secs")` and it will always be in seconds.